# Content-Seen check in Python

Tags: python, hash, web-crawler, web-scraping

Hello Guys! Let's say I have some page which I got with this script:

```
page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
```

While crawling web page, how can I efficiently (fast) check whether this content has already been crawled or not? My algorithm is like this:

```
    seenContents = set()
then check if crawled content is in set or not
```

But I do not know what to store on that set, hash value or etc? Can you recommend something?

Comment: request url may be different, but content same

Comment: @torayeff, what @mata means is adding `url` that you have already crawled to a `dict` or `set` match that instead of the content *before* crawling a page.

Comment: urls may differ, for example 2 urls may contain the same content

Comment: @torayeff - yes, but checking the url should nevertheless be the first thing to do. you can also check the content, but a dynamic page only has to include a "date/time" or "generated in ... ms" part (which many pages have) to guarantee the content will be different each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about MD5 of the content?

```
import md5

contest = "some data"
m = md5.new(contents)
m.digest()
```